# Troubleshoot product reviews

Tags: magento-1.9, review

I cannot enable product reviews on a Magento 1.9.1.1 installation.

The module output is enabled in

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Modules Output
```

However no trace of Product reviews in

```
System > Configuration > Catalog
```

or

```
Catalog
```

The website previously had installed Yotpo reviews but the module has been uninstalled.

I also verified the theme xml configuration files and there is no reviews module suppresion.

Any hints on troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this workaround:

> Check if the module is enabled in: `etc/modules/Mage_All.xml <Mage_Review>`

Then check frontend

> Switch to Default or RWD theme

Now you should be able to see the reviews block, now compare the contents of these files with your theme ones:

- `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml`
- `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/review.xml`

vs

- `app/design/frontend/{pkg}/{theme}/layout/catalog.xml`
- `app/design/frontend/{pkg}/{theme}/layout/review.xml`

and

- `app/design/frontend/{pkg}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

If you don't find any difference and/or the Reviews block is present there so the problem is in the phtml.

> Check `app/design/frontend/{pkg}/{theme}/catalog/product/view.phtml`

you must find something like that:

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
```

Comment: the etc/modules/Mage_All.xml did the job!

Comment: Cool, the short path!